# Always infeasible solution in or-tools scheduling problem

Tags: python, optimization, scheduling, or-tools

Let a list of predefined hubs with each one having a specific demand in drivers, a set of drivers and the relationship between drivers and hubs. In my example the number of drivers is way higher than the number of hubs, i.e. 400 vs 45 hubs and their demand per day is around 250 drivers. I set the constraint that each driver must have a day off as well. However, I do not get a solution to the problem and to facilitate the solution further, I even set that each driver can work at any hub (driver_hubs_relationships) and still DO not get a solution. Any ideas?

```
def create_schedule(drivers,
                    hubs,
                    hubs_and_demand,
                    driver_hubs_relationships):
    drivers_list = copy.deepcopy(drivers)
    hubs_list = copy.deepcopy(hubs)
    hubs_list_and_demand = copy.deepcopy(hubs_and_demand)
    driver_hubs_list_relationships = copy.deepcopy(driver_hubs_relationships)

    model = cp_model.CpModel()

    # Define an extra "hub" that represents a day off
    hubs_list.append('OFF')
    for e in drivers_list:
        driver_hubs_list_relationships[e].append('OFF')

    # Create variables total size len(drivers)*(1+len(hubs))*len(days)
    schedule = {}
    for e in drivers_list:
        for d in days:
            for r in hubs_list:
                schedule[(e, d, r)] = model.NewBoolVar(f'schedule_{e}_{d}_{r}')

    # Define a variable for each day representing the number of drivers having that day off
    off_days = {d: model.NewIntVar(0, len(drivers_list), f'off_{d}') for d in days}

    # Add constraints to link the off_days variable with the schedule variable
    for d in days:
        model.Add(off_days[d] == sum(schedule[(e, d, 'OFF')] for e in drivers_list))

    # Add a constraint to distribute the off days evenly across the week
    average_off_days = len(drivers_list) // len(days)
    for d in days:
        model.Add(off_days[d] >= average_off_days)

    # Each driver must have one day off per week
    for e in drivers_list:
        model.Add(sum(schedule[(e, d, 'OFF')] for d in days) == 1)

    # Each driver works at most one day at a specific hub
    for e in drivers_list:
        for d in days:
            model.Add(sum(schedule[(e, d, r)] for r in hubs_list) == 1)

    # Create variables for the number of drivers needed at each hub on each day
    drivers_needed = {}
    for d in days:
        for r in hubs_list:
            if r != 'OFF':
                hub_demand = hubs_list_and_demand.loc[hubs_list_and_demand['hub'] == r, 'drivers_needed']
                if len(hub_demand) > 0:
                    drivers_needed_at_hub = int(hub_demand.values[0])
                else:
                    drivers_needed_at_hub = 0  # or some other default value
                drivers_needed[(d, r)] = model.NewIntVar(drivers_needed_at_hub,
                                                         int(hubs_list_and_demand.max().values[1]),
                                                         f'drivers_needed_{d}_{r}')

    # Each hub needs to have the required number of drivers each day
    for d in days:
        for r in hubs_list:
            if r != 'OFF':
                model.Add(10 * sum(schedule[(e, d, r)] for e in drivers_list) >=
                          9 * drivers_needed[(d, r)])

    # Assign each driver to their specific hub
    for e in drivers_list:
        for r in hubs_list:
            if r not in driver_hubs_list_relationships[e]:
                for d in days:
                    model.Add(schedule[(e, d, r)] == 0)

    # Solve and print schedule
    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
    solver.parameters.max_time_in_seconds = 500.0
    solver.parameters.log_search_progress = True
    status = solver.Solve(model)
    print(f"status code {status}")
    if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL:
        solution = {}
        for e in drivers_list:
            solution[e] = {}
            for d in days:
                for r in hubs_list:
                    if solver.Value(schedule[(e, d, r)]) == 1:
                        print(f"{e} works at {r} on {d}")
                        solution[e][d] = r

        return solution
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: Have you tried chopping the problem down to like 5 (ish) drivers, etc ... basically a known simple example, and seeing what happens?

Comment: Also, you know your odds of getting a decent recommendation/solution go up *dramatically* if your issue is reproducible.  Right now, your code is not a reproducible example

Comment: You're absolutely right. However, my feeling is that if someone is fluent in optimisation, one can notice my potential mistake quite easily -if any

Comment: Here's a shot...below...

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a contradiction/problem with your days off:

```
# Add a constraint to distribute the off days evenly across the week
average_off_days = len(drivers_list) // len(days)
for d in days:
    model.Add(off_days[d] >= average_off_days)

# Each driver must have one day off per week
for e in drivers_list:
    model.Add(sum(schedule[(e, d, 'OFF')] for d in days) == 1)
```

If you have many excess drivers, they will likely have multiple days off, but you only allow them 1 single day off.  Try making the second constraint a GTE `>=`.

Also, it isn't clear from what you provided why you are making the days_off constraint indexed by day?  If your model is structured by meeting demand, there shouldn't be any need to force the days off by day to be a fixed amount.  And it would be odd if the "drivers with the day off" on every day were equal, which is basically what you are forcing.

##### addition:

Also it isn't clear why you are making a variable for `drivers_needed`.  That is a known (or at least a calculable) value from the data.  It is NOT unknown, is it?  I didn't follow all of the logic in that grouping of statements, but it seems you should be able to calculate the demand by day/by "hub" with a little math and make it a parameter of the model, not a variable.

Comment: I think you're right regarding your suggestions. Could you modify the code so as to give it a try with how you'd do it?

Comment: Sorry, no.  You are fairly close.  use some **small** data sets for testing.  Comment out constraints if you aren't getting any result and QA them, add them back in, etc....

Comment: if the second constraint a GTE >=. then the solver will assign OFF to all of the drivers